# How to efficiently execute a substitution command across multiple files in Vim?

Tags: vim, substitution

I want to perform a number of substitutions of the following kind across several files:

`"\includegraphics{all.png}"` → `"\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{all.png}"`

I would like to do that without Sed, using only Vim. However, when I do it, I always replace the buffer by accident with something like space so wasting a lot of keys. How can I do it fast?

*Smallest amount of keys wins!*

**Start inside Vim: getting the matches to buffers**

```
:grep -r "includegraphics" Sections/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flexible way of performing some actions in a group of files using
Vim is to collect the list of their names into the argument list (see
`:help arglist`), and then iterate through it executing the desired
command.

In order to do the first step, use commands `:args`, `:argadd`, and
`:argdelete`. For instance, to set the argument list to the names of
all files that have the `.tex` extension in the current directory and
its subdirectories, run:

```
:args ./**/*.tex
```

To perform the second step, use the `:argdo` command:

```
:argdo %s/\\includegraphics\zs\ze{all.png}/[width=\\linewidth]/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace in all buffers

`:bufdo %s/\\includegraphics\{all\.png\}/\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{all.png}/ge`

Comment: Why are you escaping `{`? It is not perl, `{` has no special meaning by default (not in very-magic mode, `:h /\v`), but `\{` does.